# htmlAttributes not merging with tag builder in my extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I am making an extension.

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("img");
    builder.MergeAttribute("src", src);
    if (htmlAttributes != null) builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

This line:

```
if (htmlAttributes != null) builder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
```

Errors with:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder.MergeAttributes<TKey,TValue>(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TKey,TValue>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

**I have tried:**

```
if (htmlAttributes != null) builder.MergeAttributes((Dictionary<string, string>)htmlAttributes);
```

and

```
if (htmlAttributes != null) builder.MergeAttributes((Dictionary<string, object>)htmlAttributes);
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to convert the anonymous type to a dictionary by creating a [`RouteValueDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx).

```
builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
```

This constructor will populate the dictionary from the properties of the object.

Answer (score 26):

It's better to use `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)` instead of new `RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes)` because it supports data dash attributes spelled with underscore (e.g. data_click) and there is no direct dependency on RouteValueDictionary.

Comment: this was really helpful to me -- I looked all around for something that like this.